# Pandas read_csv. Line Terminator showing up in String

Tags: python, pandas, newline

I have a txt file I need to load into a DataFrame, but the line terminator is showing up in some the string values. This causes an undesired output.

Here is an example of some data and how I am loading it:

```
data = '''
col1|col2|col3
vala1|vala2|vala3
valb1|val
b2|valb3
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|')
```

And the undesired output:

[image]

And this is the desired output:

[image]

The data comes from a third party and I do not have much control over how they give it to us.

Comment: There is no line terminator showing in the string, the line is simply terminating and going to the next row.  There's no way for pandas to know "valb2" should be on one line without some pre-processing.  The output is functioning as expected.

Comment: what would happen in the pre-processing step to correct this?

Comment: If I were you, I'd edit the text via string manipulation.  Think about it like this - how do *you* know "valb2" is actually one value?  Is it because each line should have three columns, and thus the line shouldn't be broken until there are two pipes (`|`)?

Comment: There you go, @Andrej Kesely just posted a pre-processing function - but note that it requires user input to determine how many columns it should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to *repair* the data, but that's heavily dependent on your input (are there any escaped separators? etc...).

Try this example:

```
data = '''
col1|col2|col3
vala1|vala2|vala3
valb1|val
b2|valb3
'''

import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from io import StringIO

def repair(data, num_cols=3):
    new_data = []
    for v, g in groupby(data.strip().splitlines(), lambda k: len(k.split('|')) == num_cols):
        if v:
            new_data.extend(g)
        else:
            new_data.append(''.join(g))
    return '\n'.join(new_data)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(repair(data, 3)), sep='|')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    col1   col2   col3
0  vala1  vala2  vala3
1  valb1  valb2  valb3
```

Comment: I think this will work. I'm lucky cause the column that's causing this isn't at the end. This seems like a hacky way of doing it, but I guess there's not much else I can do.